# error after upgrading springboot version from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a springboot application where current version of springboot used is 2.3.12.RELEASE, I needed to upgrade it as there was a security vulnerability , I tried to update the version to 2.7.0 but the code breaks throwing below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.addKeyVaultPropertySource(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.java:110)
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:47)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
at com.honeywell.CaaS.GatewayManagerAPI.webapi.SpringBootMain.main(SpringBootMain.java:51)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.Collections$SingletonList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:127)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:553)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:553)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:340)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCompletionStage.lambda$subscribe$0(MonoCompletionStage.java:77)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecretWithResponse(SecretClient.java:171)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecret(SecretClient.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultOperation.refreshProperties(KeyVaultOperation.java:139)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultOperation.<init>(KeyVaultOperation.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.addKeyVaultPropertySource(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.java:90)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.honeywell.CaaS.GatewayManagerAPI.webapi.SpringBootMain.main(SpringBootMain.java:51)Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Collections$SingletonList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.Collections$SingletonList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.util.URLUtils.serializeParameters(URLUtils.java:105)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createOauthHttpRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:51)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:36)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:117)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:63)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59)
at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
... 6 common frames omitted
```

can anyone help me ut with the issue here? the same error occurs while i try to upgrade to other versions like 2.5.12, 2.5.13 etc